# How to run 4K 60 Hz on Macbook Pro 2017 via HDMI

Tags: macos, hdmi

I have bought Dell P2415Q 4K monitor for my 13" MacBook Pro 2017, but I can't run 4K via HDMI.
I use Kingston Nucleum adapter, it actually supports HDMI 1.4, but in monitor setting there is only 30 Hz option.

I saw that using DisplayPort cable it's easy to configure 4K@60Hz, but I wonder if there is any possibility using HDMI to do that.
Any ideas?

Comment: HDMI 1.4 doesn't support 60Hz 4K

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Usb-C to DisplayPort cable is the only solution. Сable for 20$ helped me a lot.